# looping through two lists of variables and assigning the corresponding order to commands

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I have two lists of variables: 
(note in the second list, the space is the element seperator)

```
l1=(su1 su2 su3 su4)
l2=(1,2,3 4,3,2 4,7,6 3,2,1)
```

and I want to loop through both lists so that a command is executed for in the sense that `su1` goes with `1,2,3`, `su2` goes with `4,3,2`, `su3` goes with `4,7,6` and `su4` goes with `3,2,1`

So if each element of `l1` corresponds to a directory and I want to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory=/some/path
l1=(su1 su2 su3 su4)
l2=(1,2,3 4,3,2 4,7,6 3,2,1)
for i in "${l1[@]}"
do
for e in "${l2[@]}"
do
cd $directory/$i
echo "${e}" > file.txt
done
done
```

In other words, cd into each directory in `l1` and make a file using the corresponding element in `l2`

The above is what I've tried but it just makes a file using the first element of `l2` in each directory in `l1`

Comment: Should the filename in the directory `su1` for exmaple be `1,2,3`? Or shoudl there be 3 files in `su1` called `1`, `2` and `3`?

Comment: @chaos in `su1` there should be one file called file.txt containing `1,2,3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```bsh
# first create those directories
mkdir "${l1[@]}"
# set counter value to 0
c=0
# loop trough the array l1 (while the counter $c is less than the length of the array $l1)
while [ "$c" -lt "${#l1[@]}" ]; do
  # echo the corresponding value of array l2 to the file.txt in the directory
  echo "${l2[$c]}" > "${l1[$c]}/file.txt"
  # increment the counter
  let c=c+1
done
```

---

The result:

```
$ cat su1/file.txt 
1,2,3
$ cat su2/file.txt 
4,3,2
$ cat su3/file.txt 
4,7,6
$ cat su4/file.txt 
3,2,1
```

Comment: Or, loop over the indices of the first array: `for idx in "${!l1[@]}"; do something with "${l1[idx]}" and "${l2[idx]}"; done`

Comment: @glennjackman Good point didn't know that you can loop over the index values, thanks glenn!

Comment: could someone explain what `-lt` does ?

Comment: @FakeBrain Sure, it means "less than" and is from the test utillity. For all other operators see `man test`

Comment: ah ok. so because I didn't specify my exact directory structure and that those directories were already made, this seemed to work for me. Of course, wouldn't have gotten it w/o your answer 

`while [ "${c}" -lt "${#l1[@]}" ]; do
 cd ${dataDir}/${l1[$c]}/zstats/mni
 echo "${l2[$c]}" > file.txt
 let c=c+1
done`

Comment: @FakeBrain, no need to cd into the dir.  `while [ "${c}" -lt "${#l1[@]}" ]; do mkdir -p ${dataDir}/${l1[$c]}/zstats/mni ; echo "${l2[$c]}" > ${dataDir}/${l1[$c]}/zstats/mni/file.txt ; let c=c+1 ; done`.  BTW, The `mkdir -p` makes  the directory if it doesn't exist (and any parent directories that don't already exist) but doesn't error if it already exists.

Comment: @cas oh, i see now it's going down the directory path. duh. thanks for clearing that up!